# Error: Type IonTextAvatar is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using the `ion-text-avatar` module. I've imported it in the `app.module.ts` page but I still get the error as

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type IonTextAvatar is part
>   of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and
>   ConversationPageModule! Please consider moving IonTextAvatar to a
>   higher module that imports AppModule and ConversationPageModule. You
>   can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes IonTextAvatar
>   then import that NgModule in AppModule and ConversationPageModule.
>   Error: Type IonTextAvatar is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
>   AppModule and ConversationPageModule! Please consider moving
>   IonTextAvatar to a higher module that imports AppModule and
>   ConversationPageModule. You can also create a new `NgModule` that
>   exports and includes IonTextAvatar then import that `NgModule` in
>   AppModule and ConversationPageModule

This is my `conversationPage` code.

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>   
      <ion-avatar item-start ion-checkbox checked="true">
        <ion-text-avatar shape="round" class="avatar font">
          {{  }}
        </ion-text-avatar>
      <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>  
      </ion-avatar>
        <h6>{{  }}</h6>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

I have also imported & declared the module in the declarations of `conversation.module.ts`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share your two modules (App and Conversation) please?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `IonTextAvatar` is part of 2 modules, which is bad. 
 
If you use it only in your Conversation page, you should remove it from your `AppModule`, and import it only in `ConversationPageModule`:

```js
import { IonTextAvatar } from 'ionic-text-avatar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IonTextAvatar
  ]
})
export class ConversationPageModule {}
```